# PDO equivalent of odbc_tables?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, filemaker

Is there a way to get the PDO object to run the equivalent of `odbc_tables()`?  I'm working with a Filemaker database and the `DESCRIBE` sql command is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no PDO function that does this. I am not too familiar with Filemaker, but there should be some equivalent to MySQLs `SHOW TABLES`.

You will need to run the query manually and loop over the results to mimic the behavior of the `odbc_tables` method.